# Как записать историю активности процессов Windows

Tags: windows, вирусы, видеокарта, диспетчер-задач, майнинг

У меня есть подозрения на скрытый майнер в моей системе (увидел чрез MSI Afterburner, что при бездействии загрузка гп = 100%, а все остальные графики скачут в определённом диапазоне

[image: MSI Afterburner] )

Но при открытии Диспетчера задач я не могу найти процесс. Как мне его поймать? Может как то можно в фоне записывать историю работы всех процессов?

Comment: Пробовали это решение от [SU](https://superuser.com/questions/1287639/)? Конечно же необходимо выполнить стандартные действия при подозрении о наличии зловреда на машине. Быстрое выключение, загрузка с антивирусного решения LiveCD (со свежими базами!). Или подключить носители информации к другому ПК с антивирусным сканером. Сканирование и поиск зловреда. Можно просмотреть текущие TCP-сессии, иногда можно определить, что установленное соединение  работает в целях майнинга.

Comment: вышло так что сама винда нагружает видеокарту, а в дебри винды залазить не очень хочется (так как я линуксоид), я решил делать установку винды заново, а нужные файлы буду скидывать на диск и потом их проверять на линуксе, но ваш ответ помог найти мне 2 вируса, спасибо за это большое. Напишите ваш ответ чтобы я сделал его верным, ещё раз спасибо